# Backup Exec 2014 & LTO5 compression not working

Tags: backup, tape, backup-exec

I have Backup Exec 2014 (14.1 Rev 1786 64 bit)version installed on Windows 208 R2.

- IBM LTO5 (IBM ULT3580-HH5) standalone tape drive  is attached.
- Hardware compression is enabled in storage properties.
- BE Storage option 'Hardware if available otherwise none)
- We always select 'Overwrite Media' option in job properties to overwrite any existing media on tape.
- Data which is backup consists of mix files types    including MS office (majority) / Text Files / PDF / Audio / Video    etc.
- In Job Log, I can see this entry "Compression Type: Hardware"

Problem is that after writing (1,499,338,685,849 bytes in 7 hours, 57 minutes, and 56 seconds.) which is avg 1499 GB, it ejects the TAPE cartridge, and ask to insert other, which is normal because tape cartridge native capacity is 1500 GB, but my question is why its not compressing any data? as I read that LTO5 can support maximum 3TB in ideal compression conditions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The LTO drive has only 1,5TB space so you are only able to write 1,5 TB data to it. IF you Data is compressed BEFORE writing it to the LTO tape it could fit up to 3TB data.

If you check you tape overview you will see te compression rate of each tape. See picture e.g.

[image]

Comment: the pic your posted is clearing things now ,,,

What does 2,23:1 showing in your picture? how much compression is this?

Comment: & what does this picture of my last job showing ?
1.06:1 
?

Comment: I also see Soft write errors : 79 and soft read errors 16 ,    
- does this bell any ring?

Comment: 1:1 means there is no compression at all. The higher the first digit is the higher the compressing is.   2:1 would mean that you fit 2*1,38TB data to your tape.

Comment: I dont see on your pic the numer 1.06:1 but this would mean a real bad compression rate. The compression depends realy strong on the type of data you got. There are data types like *.pdf witch is allready a storng compressed format. But if you got only *.txt files for example you will be able to compress them a lot.  For other questions please post a new question